# APEX Lock and Unlock a Record

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, after-trigger

I wanted to lock and unlock records based on a check box. I know that you can do this stuff via  a validation rule but I think that is difficult to maintain if adding fields. I wrote an apex trigger using Approval.Lock. I am able to Lock the record however I am unable to grammatically unlock the records. Once the record is locked if I uncheck my ISLock before update it treats it as True. IF I use After Update the record is read only even though I am making it unlocked. Below is my code.

```
 Trigger AccountLockRecord on Account (before insert, after update) {

     List<Account> lstUnLockAccount = new List<Account>();
     List<Account> lstLockAccount = new List<Account>();

For (Account soAccount: Trigger.New){


    If (soAccount.ISLock__c = True){
        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: lOCK' );
         lstLockAccount.add(soAccount);

       // Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(lstAccount, false);

    } else If (soAccount.ISLock__c = False){

        system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'DEBUG: uNlOCK' );
          lstUnLockAccount.add(soAccount);

      //  Approval.UnlockResult[] lrList1 = Approval.unlock(lstAccount);

    }         
   }

        Approval.LockResult[] lrList1 = Approval.lock(lstLockAccount, false);
        Approval.LockResult[] lrList2 = Approval.lock(lstUnLockAccount, false);


 }
```

Comment: `lock` & `unlock` are treated as DMLs so you can't do these inside a `for` loop

Comment: Ok, fine. I did it outside of the for loop and that still gives same issue. I edited the code above

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`==` is for equality checks, `=` is for assignment. As such:

```
If (soAccount.ISLock__c = True){
```

will assign the value of true to IsLock__c, and this statement will always be true. For this reason, I always recommend that you avoid comparing to true/false values, because it can prevent typos like this from compiling.

```
If (soAccount.IsLock__c){
```